# EF Core 2.2.3 child record is not saved after update from 2.2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.2

I had the below .net Core code working with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.1.

After I upgrade the dotnet core sdk to 2.2.3 it is not working. 
Note that the related entity is not mapped with a FK in DB. I have a partial class that has the relation and has the attribute NotMapped to make this work in 2.2.1 .
 I am not sure what changed and what I need to add to save header and detail record.

```
var soHeader = new masSoHeader();
var orderToAdd = Mapper.Map(salesOrder.SalesOrderHeader, soHeader);
orderToAdd.InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now;

var newSalesOrder = _context.masSoHeader.Add(orderToAdd);


var newSoSalesOrderDetails =
    Mapper.Map<List<soSalesOrderDetail>>(salesOrder.SalesOrderDetails);

if (newSoSalesOrderDetails != null)
{
    foreach (var soSalesOrderDetail in newSoSalesOrderDetails)
    {
        soSalesOrderDetail.InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        newSalesOrder.Entity.soSalesOrderDetail.Add(soSalesOrderDetail);


    }
}


int numberOfRowsInserted = _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have something similar, I have a simple entity with a related entity (parent / child). In the view I POST only the related entity ID in the parent entity. After I POST the entity with only the related entity ID (and not the whole object), the navigation property is automatically filled with an empty object, so ModelState.IsValid will always be false, because it misses all sorts of required fields from the child object.

Comment: Does your solution uses Custom ModelBinder? I found out my solution uses a custom ModelBinder and this generates a property with an empty instantiation of that class, in stead of null. See this issue I created on Github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8713

Comment: No, I am not using Custom ModelBinder. I added the FK relation in DB and regenerated the models to make it work.